# A complete dataframe to a string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this data.frame in R;

input   output   aux

aa         bb      cc

a1         b1      c1

a2         b2      c2

I need this string

"input;output;aux#aa;bb;cc;#a1;b1;c1#a2;b2;c2"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
paste(paste(names(df1), collapse = ";"),
  do.call(paste, c(df1, sep = ";", collapse="#")), sep="#")
```

-output

```
#[1] "input;output;aux#aa;bb;cc#a1;b1;c1#a2;b2;c2"
```

---

Or using `capture.output`

```
paste(gsub("\\s+", ";", gsub("^\\d+\\s+", "", 
       trimws(capture.output(df1)))), collapse="#")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(input = c("aa", "a1", "a2"), output = c("bb", 
"b1", "b2"), aux = c("cc", "c1", "c2")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to just use `write.table`. The following gets you close:

```
capture.output(write.table(df1, sep = ";", quote = FALSE, eol = "#", row.names = FALSE))
## [1] "input;output;aux#aa;bb;cc#a1;b1;c1#a2;b2;c2#"
```

Use `sub("#$", "", ...)` to remove the last "`#`" in the output.